# Scaling large bitmap alternative approach

Tags: android, bitmap, scaling

Firstly I am aware of the recommended approach of using `inJustDecodeBounds` and `inSample` size to load bitmaps at a size close to the desired size. This is however a fairly broad approach that only gets an image approximate to the target.

I have though of utilising `options.inDensity` and `options.inTargetDensity` to trick the native loader into scaling an image more precisely to the desired target size. Basically I set `options.inDensity` to the actual width of the image and `options.inTargetDensity` to the desired width and I do indeed get an image at the desired size (aspect ration happens to remain the same in this case). I then set `image.setDensity(DENSITY_NONE)` on the resulting image and all appears to work OK.

Anyone know of anything wrong with this approach? Any thoughts on memory efficiency and image quality?

Comment: Sounds brilliant to me! (Can't believe android devs wrote the code but didn't expose the functionality in a sane and sensible way).

Comment: sounds cool! could you please post a sample ?

Comment: i think though that using inSample is more performance-optimized , no ? because it's easier for the CPU/GPU to handle sampling this way , no?

Comment: I would imagine that one could combine InSampleSize with this approach. Not tested but if you can calculate the resulting size of the image AFTER the InSampleSize effect and use this in options.inDensity it may well work.

Comment: I have now tested with inSampleSize as I suggest above and it does indeed seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have always got better image management with Opengl 2.0 and surface views.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds brilliant to me! (Can't believe android devs wrote the code but didn't expose the functionality in a sane and sensible way).

I do have one concern. I have good reason to believe that Android is unable to deal with instantiated bitmaps that are larger than 2048x2048 pixels in either dimension. If the internal code to do the rescaling isn't sufficiently intelligent, it may fail when loading bitmaps larger than 2048x2048.

Comment: I would imagine that one could combine InSampleSize with this approach. Not tested but if you can calculate the resulting size of the image AFTER the InSampleSize effect and use this in options.inDensity it may well work.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this my self, using inDensity and inTargetDensity to scale up/down bitmap on decode. It works well, but unfortunately it yields very bad performance (animation) results. I was hoping I could use this as a "universal" aproach to scale up/down on decode, similar to  inSampleSize which is unfortunately only for down sampling. Seems like there is different native implementation: inSampleSize performs well, no obvious performance impact, where inDensity/inTargetDensity introduced noticable performance impact (like slow motion).

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I suggest it would be advisable to have pre-scaled images in memory for efficient animations if memory permits.